# Using strpos, check if given URL has 'any one' of the strings in the array?

Tags: php, arrays, variables, foreach, strpos

I have a variable `$url` (who I have no control over) whose value is a URL (as a string). For example:

```
$url = 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rSnzy2dZtsE';
```

I have a list of hosts (`example.com`) that I'd like to check against the `$url`, and see if any one of them matches the host in the URL.

I am doing it like this:

```
<?php

function itsme_custom_oembed( $html, $url, $attr, $post_id ) {

    // Supported video embeds
    $hosts = array( 'blip.tv', 'money.cnn.com', 'dailymotion.com', 'flickr.com', 'hulu.com', 'kickstarter.com', 'vimeo.com', 'vine.co', 'youtube.com' );

    foreach( $hosts as $host ) {

        // check if it's a supported video embed
        if( strpos( $url, $host ) === false )
            return $html;

        return '<div class="flex-video">'. $html .'</div>';

    }

}
add_filter( 'embed_oembed_html', 'itsme_custom_oembed', 10, 4 );

?>
```

But it's not working (i.e. `strpos( $url, $host )` is always returning `false`), and as I see it, the problem is with the `foreach` construct. Especially because this works:

```
<?php

    function itsme_custom_oembed( $html, $url, $attr, $post_id ) {

        // Supported video embeds
        $host = 'youtube.com';

        // check if it's a supported video embed
        if( strpos( $url, $host ) === false )
            return $html;

        return '<div class="flex-video">'. $html .'</div>';

    }
    add_filter( 'embed_oembed_html', 'itsme_custom_oembed', 10, 4 );

?>
```

Clearly, `foreach` isn't meant for this purpose.

So, how am I supposed to check if given URL has **any one** of the strings in the array? (i.e. `true` if **any one** of the hosts in the list matches the host in the URL.)

Comment: have a look at `parse_url`, made specifically to do what you're trying to do. http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php

Comment: @scrowler Didn't notice your comment earlier. The problem isn't with parsing. It's with how I am checking/comparing.

Answer (score 3):

Problem is that you are `return`ing inside the loop. Once you `return` from a function, the function stops. So you end up checking the first value on the first run through the loop and `return` stopping the function from checking any subsequent iterations.

To fix it, you could just move the second return outside the loop. This would make the function loop over each value in the array until it found a match. If match found, function exits (`return`). If no match is found, it will hit the return after the loop.

```
function itsme_custom_oembed( $html, $url, $attr, $post_id ) {

    // Supported video embeds
    $hosts = array( 'blip.tv', 'money.cnn.com', 'dailymotion.com', 'flickr.com', 'hulu.com', 'kickstarter.com', 'vimeo.com', 'vine.co', 'youtube.com' );

    //loop over all the hosts
    foreach( $hosts as $host ) {

        // check if it's a supported video embed
        if( strpos( $url, $host ) === false )
            return $html;  //it was supported, so return from the original html from the function
    }

    //no hosts matched so return the original html wrapped in a div.
    return '<div class="flex-video">'. $html .'</div>';

}
```

Comment: I kinda understand what you are saying. Can you please provide the fix, so that I can understand it better?

Comment: @its_me updated and commented the code. Remember, `return` in a function means stop the function, return this value (whatever comes after return or null if nothing) and exit the function. The value you get out of the function is whatever is returned.

Comment: @its_me perhaps try `stripos`, case insensitive strpos.

Comment: @its_me `$success = true; foreach ($hosts as $host) { if (strpos($url, $host) === false) { $success = false; break; } } return $success ? "<div class=\"flex-video\">$html</div>" : "";` I think you are looking for something similar to that?

Comment: No luck with that either. And in order to avoid any mistakes on my end, I even tried defining the `$url` manually. Still doesn't work. E.g. http://pastebin.com/FKa1YxRG

Comment: @Sinomai Yes, something like that. I want it to return `true` if any of the strings in the array match (like `OR` not `AND`).

Comment: Reversing the order of `return`s seems to work, although I am not totally sure it's not broken somewhere. Please take a look at the update in my question.

Comment: @its_me reversing the returns would mean this: if one of the hosts in the array exist in the url, wrap with div. else, just return the original string. If thats what you want to happen, then this is the right way to do it. Remember, no one here knows what you are doing so adding stuff like "This is what I'm putting into the function" and "this is what I want out" really helps a lot. I've seen you comment "I want it to return true" which the function doesn't do anyways.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn Apologies. I didn't realize that until later. Will be more clear next time. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you want to return but you can try to use this!

```
function itsme_custom_oembed( $html, $url, $attr, $post_id ) {

    $hosts = array('blip.tv', 'money.cnn.com', 'dailymotion.com', 'flickr.com', 'hulu.com', 'kickstarter.com', 'vimeo.com', 'vine.co', 'youtube.com');
    $success = false;

    foreach ($hosts as $host) {
        if (stripos($url, $host) !== false) {
            $success = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if ($success) {
        // put your return when it DOES contain the host here
    }

    else {
        // put your return when it DOES NOT contain the host here
    }

}
```

Comment: It doesn't work. And isn't it the same as @JonathanKuhn's solution?

Comment: @its_me Did you add in return values?

Comment: Reversing the order of `return`s seems to work, although I am not totally sure it's not broken somewhere. Please take a look at the update in my question.

Comment: @its_me the problem was just that you had your returns in the wrong order originally then i guess

Comment: The problem is I still don't see why it shouldn't work either way. :P But thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

(Based on [Jonathan Kuhn's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20361141/1071413) and [suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20361093/using-strpos-check-if-given-url-has-any-one-of-the-strings-in-the-array/20362194?noredirect=1#comment30398666_20362194).) This does it:

```
<?php

function itsme_custom_oembed( $html, $url, $attr, $post_ID ) {

    // Supported video embeds
    $hosts = array( 'blip.tv', 'money.cnn.com', 'dailymotion.com', 'flickr.com', 'hulu.com', 'kickstarter.com', 'vimeo.com', 'vine.co', 'youtube.com' );

    foreach( $hosts as $host ) {

        // check if it's a supported video embed
        if( strpos( $url, $host ) !== false )
            return '<div class="flex-video">'. $html .'</div>';
        }

    }

    return $html;

}
add_filter( 'embed_oembed_html', 'itsme_custom_oembed', 10, 4 );

?>
```

Then an idea struck me; that I could do it in a much simpler way, like this:

```
<?php

function itsme_custom_oembed( $html, $url, $attr, $post_ID ) {

    // Supported video embeds
    $hosts = array( 'blip.tv', 'money.cnn.com', 'dailymotion.com', 'flickr.com', 'hulu.com', 'kickstarter.com', 'vimeo.com', 'vine.co', 'youtube.com' );

    foreach( $hosts as $host ) {

        // check if it's a supported video embed
        if( strpos( $url, $host ) !== false ) {
            $html = '<div class="flex-video">'. $html .'</div>';
            break;
        }

    }

    return $html;

}
add_filter( 'embed_oembed_html', 'itsme_custom_oembed', 10, 4 );

?>
```

Seems like a much better way to do what I am after.

Comment: Use curly braces with the `if(strpos...)` and put a `break;` on the line after `$html = ...` where you wrap `$html` with the div (inside the curly braces). This will stop the loop once a host has been found and prevent problems with double wrapping the html when more than one host exists. `http://blip.tv/money.cnn.com` is a perfectly valid url (if money.cnn.com is a folder on blip.tv) and your code will wrap `$html` with 2 divs.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn Edited out the mistakes in the answer as you suggested. Didn't really see that coming. :)